# Method does not override or implement a method from supertype for runtime camera permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-runtime

I am just invoking the run time camera permission dialog to enable the camera permission if it was disabled.

getting three problems in that:

1) Method does not override or implement a method from super type for the below method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

2) even if the camera permission is disabled its giving as '0' which is permission granted rite?

i don't know why its giving '0' when permission disabled.

Device : Samsung Galaxy s6

```
          int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera=101;
        if (mActivity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (mActivity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

3) If i enable the permission during run time, the app gets restarted which i doesn't want.

Can anyone please help me for the above three problems...

Answer (score 0):

Check your request code:

```
mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera);
```

it should be:

```
mActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Comment: Oh Sorry i have missed one line : int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera = 101;

Comment: where are u writing this code `onRequestPermissionsResult()` ?

Comment: in same class only. below to the function which is showing the run time dialog to enable the permission.